# loop, if else over hiera hash in erb template

Tags: puppet, erb, freeradius, hiera

I am almost done with my freeradius puppet module. I am facing now a problem how to loop over hash keys in an ERB template. I am using radius  for 802.1x to authenticate users. If a user is a member of a specific LDAP group, radius will assign him the vlan associated with this group and so on. This is my current configuration:

**`/etc/freeradius/sites-available/inner-tunnel`**

```
....
....
....
ldap
if (LDAP-Group == vlan_101) {
    update reply {
        Tunnel-Type = VLAN
        Tunnel-Medium-Type = IEEE-802
        Tunnel-Private-Group-ID = 101
    }
}
elsif (LDAP-Group == vlan_102) {
    update reply {
        Tunnel-Type = VLAN
        Tunnel-Medium-Type = IEEE-802
        Tunnel-Private-Group-ID = 102
    }
}
elsif (LDAP-Group == vlan_103) {
    update reply {
        Tunnel-Type = VLAN
        Tunnel-Medium-Type = IEEE-802
        Tunnel-Private-Group-ID = 103
    }
}
else {
    update reply {
        Tunnel-Type = VLAN
        Tunnel-Medium-Type = IEEE-802
        Tunnel-Private-Group-ID = 110
    }
}
  ....
  ....
  ....
```

I would like to create this file via ERB template.

**common.yaml**

```
test_freeradius::tunnel:
    'vlan_101':
        vlan: '101'
    'vlan_102':
        vlan: '102'
    'vlan_103':
        vlan: '103'
    'vlan_110':
        vlan: '110'
```

and I am using the following define.

**define test_freeradius::tunnel**

```
define test_freeradius::tunnel (

  $vlan,

){

  include test_freeradius::service

  file { '/etc/freeradius/sites-available/inner-tunnel' :
    ensure  => 'file',
    owner   => 'root',
    group   => 'freerad',
    mode    => '0644',
    content => template("${module_name}/tunnel.erb"),
    require => Class['test_freeradius::install'],
    notify  => Service['freeradius'],
  } 
}
```

and calling it now in init.pp

**init.pp**

```
....
....
$groups = hiera('test_freeradius::tunnel')
create_resources(test_freeradius::tunnel, $groups)
....
....
```

Is it possible to create the inner-tunnel file with ERB template, how could I do it? Or should I just use it as a simple file without hiera and make changes within the file?

Comment: A Puppet hash is exposed in ERB as a Ruby hash.  You can access its key set, look up values, or iterate over the whole hash via the methods provided by all Ruby hashes.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, Thanks for the reply. My problem here is the `elsif` and the `else`statements. I think just using an `if` statement will make things easier with one statement by looping over the keys and add the value. I just don't find a way to use the `elsif` and `else` statements.

Answer (score 1):

I could solve it, thus I don't know if its a clean ruby code. I had to rearrange my define because of duplicate declaration of the `file` resource.

**define test_freeradius::tunnel**

```
define test_freeradius::tunnel (

  $vlan,

){

  include test_freeradius::service

  ensure_resource('file', '/etc/freeradius/sites-available/inner-tunnel', { 
      ensure  => 'file',
      owner   => 'root',
      group   => 'freerad',
      mode    => '0644',
      content => template("${module_name}/tunnel.erb"),
      require => Class['test_freeradius::install'],
      notify  => Service['freeradius'],
    }
  )

  ensure_resource('file', '/etc/freeradius/sites-enabled/inner-tunnel', {
      ensure => 'link',
      target => '/etc/freeradius/sites-available/inner-tunnel',
    }
  )
}
```

And here is the relevant section of the tunnel.erb:

**tunnel.erb**

```
  .....
  .....
  .....
  ldap
  <% @groups.each do |key,value| -%>
  <% if key == 'vlan_10' %>
  if (LDAP-Group == vlan_10) {
      update reply {
          Tunnel-Type = VLAN
          Tunnel-Medium-Type = IEEE-802
          Tunnel-Private-Group-ID = 10
      }
  }
  <% else %>
  elsif (LDAP-Group == <%= key %>) {
    update reply {
        Tunnel-Type = VLAN
        Tunnel-Medium-Type = IEEE-802
        Tunnel-Private-Group-ID = <%= value['vlan'] %>
    }
  }  
  <% end -%>
  <% end -%>
.....
.....
.....
```

I got rid of the last `else` statement, since I'll be using an LDAP group for guest LAN and WLAN.

I'll be glad for any suggestions to make the code a bit cleaner.

Thanks!